# Better way to unit test, taking too long

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a bunch of tests its getting close to 100. They aren't unit tests anymore really they are more like integration tests. 
I was wondering if there is a better to test my code. 
I have included a sample of a test I am performing.
I need to add the wait of 1 second because I am using threads.

100 seconds every time i build seems excessive, and it will only get worse the more tests I add.

```
TEST_F(UserInterfaceTest, DownloadConfiguration)
{
downloadconfigurationcommand = commands.DownloadConfiguration(20);
    downloadconfigurationresponse = Response::GetDownloadConfigurationResponse();

    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, SetNoteBookSelection(Display::SurveyPanel));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, SaveFilePathDialog()).WillOnce(Return(wxID_OK));

    std::string val("C:\\Temp\\version20.bin");
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetSavePath()).WillOnce(Return(val));

    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, SetFunction(DOWNLOAD_CONFIGURATION));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, SetPathName(_));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, SetSurveyTimes(_));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, SetSurveyDelay(_));

    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetFunction()).WillOnce(Return(DOWNLOAD_CONFIGURATION));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetPathName()).WillOnce(Return(val));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetSurveyTimes()).WillOnce(Return(1));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_Param, GetSurveyDelay()).WillOnce(Return(20));

    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, CheckInstance(_, _));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetSerialPortInstance()).WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(serialport));
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, GetSerialPortAddress()).WillOnce(Return(port));

    EXPECT_CALL(*m_View, CustomEventDisplayData(_)).Times(AtLeast(1));

    EXPECT_CALL(serialport, Read(_))
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(downloadconfigurationresponse), Return(0)));

    EXPECT_CALL(serialport, Write(_))
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(downloadconfigurationcommand), Return(0)));

    EXPECT_EQ(wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR, m_Controller->DownloadConfiguration());

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

This is what the controller does.

```
wxThreadError wxframecontroller::DownloadConfiguration()
{
    wxThreadError err = wxTHREAD_MISC_ERROR;

    m_View->SetNoteBookSelection(Display::SurveyPanel);

    int dialog = m_View->SaveFilePathDialog();

    if (dialog == wxID_OK)
    {
        m_Param->SetFunction(DOWNLOAD_CONFIGURATION);
        m_Param->SetPathName(m_View->GetSavePath());
        m_Param->SetSurveyTimes(1);
        m_Param->SetSurveyDelay(sec_10);

        m_View->CheckInstance(m_View->GetSerialPortInstance(), m_View->GetSerialPortAddress());
        {
            CCThread* t = new CCThread(m_View, m_View->GetSerialPortInstance(), m_Param);
            err = t->Create();

            if (err != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR)
            {
                wxMessageBox(_("Couldn't create thread!"));
                delete t;
                t = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                err = t->Run();
            }

            if (err != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR)
            {
                wxMessageBox(_("Couldn't run thread!"));
                delete t;
                t = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return err;
}
```

Comment: *"I need to add the wait of 1 second because I am using threads"* - this does not sound right.

Comment: I don't think it is right either, hence the question. I need the wait though for the code to work, if i don't the unit test carries on to the next one and the program crashes because all the variables have been released.

Comment: You could synchronize using a std::mutex, instead of waiting an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: I would mock the thread you created inside your code, and use your mocked thread to invoke a mocked run method.

Comment: `CCThread* t` might leak (when `err = t->Run();` returns `wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR`). The pointer seems unneeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you add a sleep to a test you're actually waiting for something else to happen, but not synchronizing with it. Look at any sleep in your tests with great suspicion.

Try to write your code such that you can test the functionality separate from the threading. If you cannot do that, make the test join the threads at the end (so that you know that your test tear-down actually tore down the whole test).

Note that your test currently would randomly fail if your computer is more highly loaded - this alone is an indication your test is unstable.

Comment: I tried to make the thread joinable and removed the sleep.  I am having issues with this section of code because the thread is trying to post an event but the test has alraedy moved on. if (m_Function == download_config)
 {

  DownloadConfig(m_PathName);
                // it crashes at this point.
  CloseConnection(std::string("closing comports\n"));

  return 0;
 } How do i notify the test to wait for the thread to finish?

Comment: I got it to synchronize now thanks reduced the wait by a factor of 4. I added a semaphore to the controller, and pass it to the thread constructor and call semaphore wait at the end of the test.